# Display `grep -lr` results as a tree

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, tree, indentation

I'm searching a large number of text files which are organized in various subdirectories. I can run a command such as `grep -lr foobar ./`, and I get results like the following:

```
./dirA/dirA.A/abc.txt
./dirA/dirA.A/def.txt
./dirA/dirA.A/dirA.A.A/ghi.txt
./dirA/dirA.B/jkl.txt
./dirB/mno.txt
```

I would like some way to display these in a visual tree, similar to how the `tree` command works. Something roughly like this:

```
./
  dirA/
    dirA.A/
      abc.txt
      def.txt
      dirA.A.A/
        ghi.txt
    dirA.B/
      jkl.txt
  dirB/
    mno.txt
```

It seems like it'd be trivial to do this in some Python script with a stack, but I'd really like some way to do this straight from bash if there's a way to do it. So I guess I'm looking for a way to either (a) format/transform the output of `grep`, OR (b) some other generic "indent-by-common-prefix" utility that I've so-far been unable to find.

Comment: I would be strongly tempted to leave the `/` suffix on each level of the tree. Otherwise, there is no way to distinguish between a regular file and an empty directory.

Comment: Good point. I'll change the example. My actual output requirements aren't very strict, just "some sort of visual tree".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution using a version of `tree` which is newer than what was installed on my system. Version 1.8.0 of `tree` (released 11/16/2018) introduced the `--fromfile` parameter, which reads a directory/file listing from a file (or `stdin`) rather than the filesystem itself and generates a tree representation:

```
$ grep -rl 'foobar' ./ |tree --fromfile -F .
./
└── ./
    ├── dirA/
    │   ├── dirA.A/
    │   │   ├── abc.txt
    │   │   ├── def.txt
    │   │   └── dirA.A.A/
    │   │       └── ghi.txt
    │   └── dirA.B/
    │       └── jkl.txt
    └── dirB/
        └── mno.txt

6 directories, 5 files
```

For reference:

- http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/tree.1.html
- http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/changes.html

Comment: You could add the `-F` option to add a trailing `/` to directories.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `tree` takes a newline-delimited list on input rather than a null-delimited ones (like with the `--file0-from` of several GNU utilities) as that means it can't render arbitrary file names.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Aah good thought. I'll update the example. Thanks!